# Why will this loop not repeat itself in the order of the statements?

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I am having trouble sorting out a loop in my program which does not behave a I would expect. This program lets you play "Connect Four". I included the full (runnable code) and the excerpt that troubles me at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pygame
import time

BOARD_SIZE = 6
BOARD_BOX_NUM = BOARD_SIZE ** 2
GIVEN_IDS = 0

# ------------------------------- setting up pygame  --------------------------------------------
pygame.init()

display_height = 600
display_width = 600

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# ------------------------------- colours ----------------------------------------------------

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

blue = (0,0,255)
light_blue = (30, 144, 255)

red = (200, 0, 0)
light_red = (255, 0, 0)

yellow = (200, 200, 0)
light_yellow = (255, 255, 0)

green = (34, 177, 76)
light_green = (0, 255, 0)

# ------------------------------- methods for the game algorythm ------------------------------


def rolling_window(a, size):
    # This method is required for the algorythm that broadcasts the board for a win
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - size + 1, size)
    strides = a.strides + (a. strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


class Chip:
    def __init__(self, colour):
        if colour == "Blue":
            self.colour = colour
        if colour == "Red":
            self.colour = colour
        global GIVEN_IDS
        self.iD = GIVEN_IDS
        GIVEN_IDS += 1

    def get_iD(self):
        return self.iD


class Game:
    def __init__(self, player_colour="Blue", comp_colour="Red"):
        self.board = np.empty(BOARD_BOX_NUM, dtype=Chip)
        self.board = self.board.reshape(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE)
        self.player_colour = player_colour
        self.comp_colour = comp_colour

    def get_comp_colour(self):
        return self.comp_colour

    def get_player_colour(self):
        return self.player_colour

    def give_str_board(self):
        """Returns a copy of the board array and replaces the Chip objects with the str with the colour of the chips."""
        this_board = np.copy(self.board)
        for x, y in np.ndindex(this_board.shape):
            if this_board[x, y] is not None:
                if this_board[x, y].colour == "Blue":
                    this_board[x, y] = "Blue"
                else:
                    this_board[x, y] = "Red"
        return this_board

    def print_board_in_console(self):
        """This function holds the board which is a 8x8 matrix."""
        this_board = self.give_str_board()
        print(this_board)
        print("-"*40)

    def insert_chip(self, chip, col):
        """Method for making a new entry to the board. For the player and enemy.
            The column has to be parametrised in the pythonic way. i.e. cols from 0-7."""
        # slices the entries of the column into a new array
        col_entries = self.board[:, col:col+1]
        # checks for all unoccupied pos in this column(entries are None)
        # double array of indexes with the form (array([row_i, ...]), array([column_i, ...]))
        # checking the condition with "is" is here not possible, because "is" operator cannot be overloaded
        none_indexes = np.where(col_entries == None)
        # check whether the column cannot contain an extra chip and function has to be aborted
        if len(none_indexes[0]) == 0:
            print("This column is full. Chose again.")
            return False
        # the pos where the chip will fall is the one with the highest index
        self.board[len(none_indexes[0]) - 1, col] = chip
        return True

    def get_chip(self, x, y):
        """This function can return the information about a chip in a pos of the board."""
        chip = self.board[x, y]
        return chip

    def is_won(self):
        """This function can be used to check the board on whether the game has been decided.
            The function differentiates between player and enemy and returns..."""
        winning_chip = None
        # get a copy of the board which only contains str and None
        this_board = self.give_str_board()
        flipped_board = np.fliplr(this_board)

        # in order to check the entire board for 4 Chips in a formation individual rows and cols are examined
        # use for loops to isolate rows and cols
        for this_ax in range(0, 2):
            for index in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
                # the stack will contain the row[index] when this_ax = 0 and the col[index] when this_ax = 1
                stack = this_board.take(index, axis=this_ax)

                # this will be the patterns, that are searched for
                winning_formations = [['Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'], ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']]
                for i in winning_formations:
                    bool_array = rolling_window(stack, 4) == i

                    if [True, True, True, True] in bool_array.tolist():
                        # the stack_index is the index of the first chip in the 4xChip formation in the row/col
                        stack_index_tuple, = np.where(np.all(bool_array == [True, True, True, True], axis=1))
                        stack_index = stack_index_tuple[0]
                        loop_index = index
                        # this_ax = 0 means loop_index is row and stack_index is col
                        if this_ax == 0:
                            winning_chip = self.get_chip(loop_index, stack_index)
                            break
                        else:
                            winning_chip = self.get_chip(stack_index, loop_index)
                            break

            # This next part of the algorythm checks whether diagonal patterns of the array
            # contain a winning formation

            # if this bit is problematic: change the 0 in range()!!!

            for index in range(0, BOARD_SIZE - 2):
                for board in [this_board, flipped_board]:
                    diag_elements = board.diagonal(index)
                    for i in winning_formations:
                        bool_array = rolling_window(diag_elements, 4) == i
                        if [True, True, True, True] in bool_array.tolist():
                            # the stack_index is the index of the first chip in the 4xChip formation in the row/col
                            diag_el_index_tuple, = np.where(
                                np.all(bool_array == [True, True, True, True], axis=1))
                            diag_index = diag_el_index_tuple[0]
                            loop_index = index
                            # this_ax = 0 means loop_index is row and stack_index is col
                            if board == this_board:
                                winning_chip = self.get_chip(loop_index, diag_index)
                                break
                            else:
                                winning_chip = self.get_chip(diag_index, loop_index)
                                break

        if winning_chip is not None:
            return winning_chip.colour

        return None

    def get_comp_move(self):
        """This method generates the computer's move (the column) based on INTELLIGENCE!!!!
        Returns the column of the move"""
        c_colour = self.get_comp_colour()
        p_colour = self.get_player_colour()

        # check, if the comp can win in the next move
        for i in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
            board = self.give_str_board()
            chip = Chip(c_colour)
            self.insert_chip(chip, i)
            if self.is_won() == c_colour:
                return i

        # check, if the player can win in the next move and block that position
        for i in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
            board = self.give_str_board()
            chip = Chip(p_colour)
            self.insert_chip(chip, i)
            if self.is_won() == p_colour:
                return i

        # accumulate preferable positions for the next move
        good_spots = []
        board = self.give_str_board()
        for axis in range(0, 2):
            for index in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
                # the stack will contain the row[index] when this_ax = 0 and the col[index] when this_ax = 1
                stack = board.take(index, axis=axis)

                # this will be the patterns, that are searched for
                for i in [c_colour, c_colour]:
                    bool_array = rolling_window(stack, 2) == i

                    if [True, True] in bool_array.tolist():
                        # the stack_index is the index of the first chip in the 4xChip formation in the row/col
                        stack_index_tuple, = np.where(np.all(bool_array == [True, True], axis=1))
                        stack_index = stack_index_tuple[0]
                        # this_ax = 0 means loop_index is row and stack_index is col
                        if axis == 0:
                            # "- 1" because this if-statement is called when broadcasting a row. i.e. column before
                            good_spots.append(stack_index - 1)
                        else:
                            good_spots.append(index)
            # The pick is the x-coo of the first of a series of two chips (column) or the x before (row).
            print(good_spots)
            pick = random.randint(0, len(good_spots))
            return pick

        # make a move, "better than nothing"
        flag = True
        while flag is True:
            rnd = random.randint(0, BOARD_SIZE)
            if self.board[rnd, 0] is None:
                return rnd

    # ------------------------------- this part will take care of the visualisation in pygame ------------------------

    # buttons = []
    #
    # def button(self, text, x, y, radius, inactive_colour, active_colour, action=None, size=" "):
    #     cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    #     if x + radius > cur[0] > x - radius and y + radius > cur[1] > y - radius:
    #         pygame.draw.circle(game_display, active_colour, (x, y), radius)
    #
    #         ix = None
    #         iy = None
    #         for event in pygame.event.get():
    #             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    #                 ix, iy = event.pos
    #
    #         if ix is not None and iy is not None:
    #             if x + radius > ix > x - radius and y + radius > iy > y - radius and action is not None:
    #                 if action == "quit":
    #                     pygame.quit()
    #                     quit()
    #
    #                 if action == "move":
    #                     col = int(x / 80 - 90)
    #                     self.insert_chip(Chip(self.get_player_colour()), col)
    #     else:
    #         pygame.draw.circle(game_display, inactive_colour, (x, y), radius)

    def draw_board(self):
        board = self.give_str_board()
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, green, (60, 60, 80*BOARD_SIZE, 80*BOARD_SIZE))
        for y in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
            for x in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):
                dx = 90 + x * 80
                dy = 90 + y * 80
                if board[x, y] is None:
                    pygame.draw.circle(game_display, white, (dy, dx), 30)
                elif board[x, y] == "Blue":
                    pygame.draw.circle(game_display, blue, (dy, dx), 30)
                elif board[x, y] == "Red":
                    pygame.draw.circle(game_display, red, (dy, dx), 30)

        # draw the selector square
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, yellow, (self.selector_pos * 80 + 80, 60, 20, 20))

    selector_pos = 0

    def move_selector(self, dir):
        selector_pos = self.selector_pos
        if dir == 'left' and selector_pos >= 0:
            new_x = selector_pos * 80 - 80
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, yellow, (new_x, 60, 20, 20))
            self.selector_pos -= 1
        if dir == 'right' and selector_pos <= BOARD_SIZE - 1:
            new_x = selector_pos * 80 + 80
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, yellow, (new_x, 60, 20, 20))
            self.selector_pos += 1

    def intro(self):
        return

    def game_loop(self, comp_goes_first=False):

        game_over = False
        while game_over is not True:

            # here comes the computer's move
            if comp_goes_first is True:
                col = self.get_comp_move()
                chip = Chip(self.get_comp_colour())
                self.insert_chip(chip, col)

            # This will be the player move
            move_over = False
            while move_over is not True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    print(event)
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            self.move_selector('right')
                            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, yellow, (50, 50, 50, 50))
                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            self.move_selector('left')
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            # the selector position indicates the column which the player has chosen.
                            col = self.selector_pos
                            chip = Chip(self.get_player_colour())
                            move_over = self.insert_chip(chip, col)

                game_display.fill(white)
                self.draw_board()
                pygame.display.update()

            comp_goes_first = True
            clock.tick(15)


game = Game()
game.game_loop()
```

Now to the part that particularly leaves me in doubt.

As the following loop runs, I can make the Player's move in the game as expected with the use of arrow keys and return, however then the program goes crazy. It will do multiple moves for the computer and sometimes the player as well. This is a picture of the GUI after the loop has run once (player's move and then the computer's move and now it would be the players move again).

[image: GUI]

At this point I am wondering whether I got something fundamentally wrong with the while loop construction here and I cannot figure it out. What is the issue?

```
game_over = False
    while game_over is not True:

        # here comes the computer's move
        if comp_goes_first is True:
            col = self.get_comp_move()
            chip = Chip(self.get_comp_colour())
            self.insert_chip(chip, col)

        # This will be the player move
        move_over = False
        while move_over is not True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.move_selector('right')
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.move_selector('left')
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        # the selector position indicates the column which the player has chosen.
                        col = self.selector_pos
                        chip = Chip(self.get_player_colour())
                        move_over = self.insert_chip(chip, col)

            game_display.fill(white)
            self.draw_board()
            pygame.display.update()

        comp_goes_first = True
        clock.tick(15)
```

Comment: Please pare down your submission so we can actually go through an review it. Questions like, "why doesn't this work?" and big globs of code are very difficult to review and will likely result in no help to you.

Comment: @Woody1193 I made an edit to the question and hope you can elaborate on your answer. Actually I just included the entire code for the project in case somebody wanted to run it,

Comment: Nobody wants/needs to run your entire project to help you with your problem. In fact, if that's the case then you probably haven't designed things right in the first place. Rather, you should post a very small example that I don't have to spend hours looking at before I can comprehend it. Otherwise it'll be much more difficult for someone to help you

Comment: @Woody1193 alright.. I think I just found the source of my error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks to me to be in your AI logic. You're making a copy of the board for the AI to experiment on, but then you're not using it, and instead inserting chips into the real board.

```
# check, if the comp can win in the next move
        for i in range(0, BOARD_SIZE):

            # Never used.
            board = self.give_str_board()
            chip = Chip(c_colour)

            # inserting onto the real board.
            self.insert_chip(chip, i)
            print("insert check", board, self)
            if self.is_won() == c_colour:
                return i
```

Comment: I'm still busy troubleshooting, but this was a major issue

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with the trouble shooting. What you've made so far is pretty neat.